# Creating a Score Method for an Array

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, methods

My goal is to create a score method for a simple game based in an array. The game consists of putting 'R's or 'B's in one of 11 positions in an array. Once the array is full, the score method will execute as follows:

Any single 'R' or 'B' is worth 0 points

Any pair of 'R's or 'B's is worth 4 points

Any triple of 'R's or 'B's is worth 6 points

... and so on.

I'm having trouble calculating the score and I feel like I am missing something obvious so I'm coming here. The code I have looks for pairs and adds 2 to the score, but I end up missing 2 points (since the first pair is worth 4 and each additional "pair" is worth another 2).

```
public int score(char color)
{
    int score = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < gameBoard.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        if (gameBoard[i] == color && gameBoard[i + 1] == color)
            score += 2;
        else
            score += 0;
    }

    return score;
}
```

Comment: are triple (3) r's worth 6 points or is two consecutive pair (4) of r's worth 6 points

Comment: Each letter in a pair is worth 2 points. So if you have the sequence RRBRB, R gets 4 points. Or RRRBBRB, R has 6 points, B has 4.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem can be solved by regular expressions.

```
public int CalculateScore(char color)
{
    var boardStr = String.Join("", gameBoard);
    return GetCharacterSequences(color, boardStr)
        .Sum(str => str.Length * 2);
}

//Returns same character sequences of length more than two.
private IEnumerable<string> GetCharacterSequences(char color, string boardStr)
{
    return Regex.Matches(boardStr, $@"({color})\1+").OfType<Match>()
        .SelectMany(match => match.Groups.OfType<Group>())
        .Select(@group => @group.Value)
        .Where(str => str.Length > 1);
}
```

Idea of sum function: Each pair costs 4 points, each triple costs 6 points hence each single char costs 2 points.

`GetCharacterSequences` looks little bit complex but it makes `CalculateScore` method very simple.

Comment: Elegant solution - rather advanced for what is most likely a homework assignment, but elegant nonetheless :)

Answer (score 0):

Well you could create a boolean variable and use that to determine the number of points added.

Note: This code doesn't account for triple matches as you've mentioned in your question.

```
public int score(char color)
{
    int score = 0;
    bool firstMatch = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < gameBoard.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        if (gameBoard[i] == color && gameBoard[i + 1] == color) {
            if (firstMatch == true) {
                score += 4;
                firstMatch = false;
            } else {
                score += 2;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            score += 0;
        }
    }
    return score;
}
```

Comment: I used his code as a reference to show him a possible method of catering to each point bracket.

Comment: "The code I have looks for pairs and adds 2 to the score, but I end up missing 2 points (since the first pair is worth 4 and each additional "pair" is worth another 2)." 

I was answering this particular statement and based on his code, made alterations. However I realize it doesn't fulfil the complete task as OP would want. I'll edit it with a better version.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach, based on a pair being 4 points, 3 being 6 points, and assuming 4 being 8 points and so forth (basically number of adjacent colors * 2 if there is at least a pair).

```
public int score(char color)
{

    int adj = 0;
    int score = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < gameBoard.Length; i++)
    {
        if (gameBoard[i] == color)
        {
            adj++;
        }
        else
        {
            if (adj > 1)
            {
                score += adj * 2;
            }
            adj = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

This code loops through the array, and keeps a count of the number of adjacent spots marked by the specified color.  When it comes to an element of the array that is not the right color, it checks to see how many adjacent elements had the correct color.

If it's greater than 1, then it multiplies the number of adjacent elements by 2 and resets the adjacent elements counter to 0 and continues through the array.

Given an array of 'R', 'R', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'B', 'R', 'B', it produces a score of 10 for 'R' (4 + 6) and 6 for 'B' (6), as follows:

```
'R', 'R' = 4
'R', 'R', 'R' = 6
'R' = 0

'B', 'B', 'B' = 6
'B' = 0
```

Comment: I really appreciate the simplicity of this. However, testing produces varied results. RRRRRR BBBBBB gives R=12 and B=0; BR BBB RR B RRR gives R=4, B=6

Comment: The current code I posted doesn't handle the end of the array correctly.  I have another idea but won't be able to post it until later.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i came up with

```
namespace TestApp1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string[] test = GetValues();
            string testView = String.Join(String.Empty, test);
            string score = GetScore(test).ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(testView);
            Console.WriteLine(score);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static int GetScore(string[] test)
        {

            int score = 0;
            int occurence = 0;
            string LastChar = string.Empty;

            for (int i = 0; i < test.Length; i++)
            {

                if(LastChar == string.Empty)
                {
                    LastChar = test[i];
                    occurence += 1;
                    continue;
                }

                if(LastChar == test[i])
                {
                    occurence += 1;

                    if(i == test.Length - 1)
                    {
                        if (occurence > 1)
                        {
                            score += occurence * 2;
                        }
                    }

                }
                else
                {

                    if(occurence > 1)
                    {
                        score += occurence * 2;
                    }

                    LastChar = test[i];
                    occurence = 1;

                }

            }

            return score;

        }


        public static string[] GetValues()
        {

            List<string> values = new List<string>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
            {

                var rnd = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
                int ticks = rnd.Next(0, 2);

                values.Add(ticks == 1 ? "R" : "B");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2);

            }

            return values.ToArray();

        }

    }

}
```

To calculate each score independently

```
namespace TestApp1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string[] test = GetValues();
            string testView = String.Join(String.Empty, test);
            int rScore = 0;
            int bScore = 0;

            GetScore(test,out rScore, out bScore);

            string score = "R: " + rScore.ToString() + "  B: " + bScore.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(testView);
            Console.WriteLine(score);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void GetScore(string[] test, out int rScore, out int bScore)
        {

            int occurence = 0;
            string LastChar = string.Empty;

            rScore = 0;
            bScore = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < test.Length; i++)
            {

                if(LastChar == string.Empty)
                {
                    LastChar = test[i];
                    occurence += 1;
                    continue;
                }

                if(LastChar == test[i])
                {
                    occurence += 1;

                    if(i == test.Length - 1)
                    {
                        if (occurence > 1)
                        {
                            if(LastChar == "R")
                            {
                                rScore += occurence * 2;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                bScore += occurence * 2;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
                else
                {

                    if(occurence > 1)
                    {
                        if (LastChar == "R")
                        {
                            rScore += occurence * 2;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            bScore += occurence * 2;
                        }
                    }

                    LastChar = test[i];
                    occurence = 1;

                }

            }

        }


        public static string[] GetValues()
        {

            List<string> values = new List<string>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
            {

                var rnd = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
                int ticks = rnd.Next(0, 2);

                values.Add(ticks == 1 ? "R" : "B");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2);

            }

            return values.ToArray();

        }

    }

}
```